# Ruby OptionParser: How do I get the PATH? if the command is just "command path/to/some/file"?

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want create a command that has the following structure `command path/to/some/file`

How do I enable this without entering the option -p or --path?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'optparse'

options = {}
option = OptionParser.new() do |opts|

    opts.on('-p PATH', '--path PATH', 'First path argument') do |path| // How do I enable this without entering the option -p or --path? 
       options[:path] = path
    end
end

option.parse!(ARGV)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not stated very explicitly in the docs, but `OptionParser` will extract all options from `ARGV` and leave the rest, so the right way is just to use `ARGV` as if it were the list of paths.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt `ARGV[0]` give you access to the first part of your argument? In your case this would be the path, aka `path/to/some/file`. The whole parser code is not necessary here imo.

Comment: Yes, but is it "the right way" of doing this? because I can will pass other arguments as well so ARGV[0] can sometimes not be the path?

Comment: Then just check the ARGV[0] after processing with the parser. That way you remove all the options from the ARGV array and what is left over should be the path.